# MongoDB $lookup function replace whole document

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework, aggregate, lookup, unwind

I'm currently running a query that looks like this:

```
courses = await Enrollment.aggregate([
        {
            $match: {
                userId: userId
            }
        },
        {
            $lookup: {
                from: 'courses',
                localField: 'course',
                foreignField: '_id',
                as: 'course'
            }
        },
        { 
            $unwind: '$course'
        },
        {
            $project: {
                course: {
                    courseCode: true,
                    name: true,
                    officialCode: true,
                }
            }
        }
    ]);
```

This produces results that look like this

```
[{
    "_id": "61e0652ba5c2fe5bdcdbdc23",
    "course": {
        "courseCode": "code2",
        "name": "Terst class 2",
        "officialCode": "test 202"
    }
}]
```

I'm wondering if there is a way for me to bring `courseCode`, `name` and `officialCode` to the "highest level" of the document?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Add stage `{$replaceWith: "$course"}`

Comment: project or replaceRoot can do it, replaceRoot can do it without naming the fields so its more flexible [test code here](https://cmql.org/play/?q=1642101787048)

Comment: Just a note, `$replaceWith` and `$replaceRoot` is the same operator, just slightly different syntax.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it with `$replaceRoot` aggregation pipeline. Add this as the last step:

```js
{
  "$replaceRoot": {
    "newRoot": "$course"
  }
}
```

[Working example](https://mongoplayground.net/p/MpihfvYltHo)